# Use COALESCEC to fill missing values

Tags: sas

Would someone confirm that the COALESCE or COALESCEC function is the correct command to use for the following?

I would like to assign a matching value from a non-missing corresponding observation to that of a missing observation.

So, if data looks like:

```
 Order  |   ID  
 apple     101xa  
 orange    201xb
 cherry    301xc
 apple       .
```

I will end up with:

```
 Taxo  |   Specialty2  
 apple     101xa  
 orange    201xb
 cherry    301xc
 apple     101xa
```

Thanks for the support!

EDIT: Current Code used--

```
proc sort data=fill; 
    by taxo descending specialty2;
run;

data fill_input;
    set fill;
        retain tempspecialty2;
        length tempspecialty2 $5;
            by taxo;
                if first.taxo then tempspecialty2=' ';
                if not missing(specialty2) then tempspecialty2=specialty2;
                else tempspecialty2=specialty2;
run;

proc freq data=fill_input;
    table tempspecialty2;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data step functions don't quite work that way; crossing the row boundary requires you to save the value in a temporary variable.

What you would need to do would be to sort by `order`.  Then you can save the value of ID in a temporary retained variable, and use it if needed.

```
proc sort data=have; 
by order;
run;

data want;
set have;
retain tempID;
length tempID $5;
by order;
if first.order then tempID=' ';
if not missing(id) then tempID=id;
else id=tempID;
run;
```

If you cannot change the order of rows, then you would need to solve this in a different way, using a hash table or a format or something similar.

Comment: How would I control to make sure the first `Order` does not correspond with a missing `ID` ?

Or is there a way to create a new variable, `ID` ?

Comment: That depends on your rules - ie, how do you know which one is right if you have multiple?  If you don't care and just want any arbitrary ID gets filled in, then sort `by order descending id;` which will put missing IDs on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Joe! The inputs have already been validated, so it is really a focus on the missing. However, I used, what I believe to be the adapted code, and it does not seem to be correcting for the missing obs. Any insight?